# View files on linux remotely from browser

Tags: html, linux

I have an HTML file that contains some data on different (text) files as well as where they are located locally on a linux machine.
This file is meant to be sent as an email, with the file locations being anchor tags.
I want to use my browser (Google Chrome) to view some files that are on that remote linux machine.

What I mean by that is the following:

1. View the HTML file in the browser of any PC (In this case multiple ones running windows)
2. When I click on the link, the file should open in browser (without downloading) as just plain text.

Basically I want to remotely view these files like how I can view anything on my local pc through my browser.

Is that even possible? If it is, please explain to me how it is done.
If not, can you suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Linux system that houses text files should have a server installed and firewall set. that serves required text files. Server can be any if you only need serving static files and not need any authentication or business logic. nginx and apache can do the job. and just in response header include

`Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.pdf"`

to force file to be viewed in browser.